# Swagger UI getting 403 error even after adding resources in the ignored list & overriding resourceHandlers

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, pom.xml, swagger-ui

I have tried implementing swagger2 to my spring boot project with

dependencies in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

adding resources in the ignored list for spring security

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger.json");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
    }
```

also tried adding this in overriden config method

```
 .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
```

swagger config class:
I have tried BOTH to my Swagger config class

```
implements WebMvcConfigurer 
extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
```

as suggested in other answers

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String TITLE;

    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "API Documentation";

    /**
     * Providing app information to swagger
     * @return ApiInfo
     */
    private ApiInfo apiInfo()
    {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(TITLE)
                .description(DESCRIPTION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

and these in my properties file

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

still am getting

```
Access to localhost was denied
You don't have authorisation to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

can someone advise with this swagger configuration error please

Comment: can you access it when you use `web.antMatchers("/**").permitAll();`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing at least one resource `(configuration/ui)` unreachable, the following would do the trick.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                                   "/configuration/ui",
                                   "/swagger-resources/**",
                                   "/configuration/security",
                                   "/swagger-ui.html",
                                   "/webjars/**");
    }
```

Comment: thanks so much for replying @gsan , actually i had tried that with different resource set, but the error still persisted, now the issue has been resolved when i tuned down the version for springfox in pom from 3 -> 2.8

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem with spring-boot v3.

In this case, you need to use: [springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui/2.0.2) as it is writen in the [doc introduction](https://springdoc.org/#Introduction)

And use security configuration, something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                       .requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
               ).build();
   }


}
```

Swagger UI: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

JSON: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs

yaml: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml

If you run your application on localhost:8080 :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue got resolved when I changed to the previous version of springfox in pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

NOTE:
seems like springfox v3 is unstable,
while using v3 the application was not starting due to some error which was later resolved by solution online - adding following pathmaker property

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```